# Python Regular Expression Question

Tags: python, regex

Say I have text 'C:\somedir\test.log' and I want to replace 'somedir' with 'somedir\logs'.

So I want to go from 'C:\somedir\test.log' to 'C:\somedir\logs\test.log'

How do I do this using the re library and re.sub?

I've tried this so far:

```
find = r'(C:\\somedir)\\.*?\.log'
repl = r'C:\\somedir\\logs'
print re.sub(find,repl,r'random text ... C:\somedir\test.log more \nrandom \ntext C:\somedir\test.xls...')
```

But I just get 'C:\somedir\logs'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to introduce a different grouping in order for the replace to work as you want, and then need to refer to that group with the replacement expression. See [Python's re.sub documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) for another example.

Try:

```
find = r'C:\\somedir\\(.*?\.log)'
repl = r'C:\\somedir\\logs\\\1'
print re.sub(find,repl,r'random text ... C:\somedir\test.log more \nrandom \ntext C:\somedir\test.xls...')
```

This results in output:

```
'random text ... C:\somedir\logs\test.log more \nrandom \ntext C:\somedir\test.xls...'
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's exactly what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using the [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) library to do this. Specifically, [os.path.join](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) and [os.path.split](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.split).

This way it will work on all operating systems and will account for edge cases.

Comment: You're right, but for curiosity's sake, how would I do this with re.sub?

Answer (score 2):

ikanobori is correct, but you should also not be using re for simple string substitution.

```
r'C:\somedir\test.log'.replace('somedir', r'somedir\logs')
```

Comment: I updated my example to show why this wouldn't work.  I'm curious how to do it with re.sub regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, if you really want a way to do it with regular expressions, here's one:

```
find = r'(C:\\somedir\\.*?\.log)'
def repl(match):
    return match.groups()[0].replace('somedir', r'somedir\logs')
s = r'random text ... C:\somedir\test.log more \nrandom \ntext C:\somedir\test.xls...'
print re.sub(find, repl, s)
```